# Is there a random number generator with splitting and limits?

Tags: java, random, int, double

I am looking to create some code. Which will consist of a number input, which will randomly split into 4 different places, each place has a limit which it cannot exceed. I would like to use decimals, but using an int and then adding a decimal later just for presentation will also work in my case. I will give an example here.

Input 4920

1 cannot exceed 6500,
2 cannot exceed 1700,
3 cannot exceed 9000,
4 cannot exceed 1700

But each time i need where the numbers go to be completely random, so each place returns a different number each time while none exceed their limits. They can equal to their limits, but i would like the numbers not to be at their maximums all the time, or 3 to be max and one to be below.

I dont really know where to start with this, at this stage all i have done is been able to use a percentage to workout where they go. Basic, but no randomness to it without checks. Input will never exceed 4950 as i will make it throw and error if user tries to input higher.

Below is the basic idea, but this will always result in a percentage, so whatever number is entered will yield the same results. Im simply looking for this but with randomness to it.

Its for calculating axle weights in a truck by spreading the gross mass over all the axle groups, but there are limits on each axle group. Hence the gross cannot and willnot exceed 49.50 and the axle groups cannot exceed 6.5, 17.0, 9.0 and 17.0 in this truck combination.

This code below is basically what we do now manually, but would like some randomness to it so its not always the same results

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    double GrossWeight, SteerWeight, DriveWeight, DollyWeight, BogieWeight;
    System.out.println("PBS2 3 Axle Truck and 3 Axle Dog Combination Only");
    System.out.print("Enter Gross Weight:");
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    GrossWeight = Scan.nextDouble();

    SteerWeight = (GrossWeight/0.1313);
    System.out.print("Steer Axle Weight:");
    System.out.println(SteerWeight);

    DriveWeight = (GrossWeight/0.3434);
    System.out.print("Drive Axle Weight:");
    System.out.println(DriveWeight);

    DollyWeight = (GrossWeight/0.1818);
    System.out.print("Dolly Axle Weight:");
    System.out.println(DollyWeight);

    BogieWeight = (GrossWeight/0.3434);
    System.out.print("Bogie Axle Weight:");
    System.out.println(BogieWeight);
    }
```

}

Comment: To be honest I don't get your example and I don't get what you are trying to achieve. What do you want to split? How are those limits related to the input, e.g. if the input cannot be higher than 4950 why is there a limit of 6500 or 9000? What do those numbers mean?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random.nextInt(int bound)` to generate a new random number between 0 and your desired bound.
If I understood your use case correctly, you want to the random numbers to depend on your input so feel free to write a method that calculates this bound based on your input.

Be aware that `nextInt(int bound)` returns a random number between 0 (0 is included) and your bound which es **excluded**.